# Why can't I see node names in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

In the visualization, a lot of nodes don't show their node names. They look blank. Is that because for the node, I didn't create a 'name' attribute for it? In another words, in order to show the node with a text, must I create a 'name' property for that node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default neo4j looks for a `name` property to show as the node caption. But you can change it. In the admin console, write your cypher to get a graph back. Then at the top click on the label of the nodes you want to change caption for. Then at the bottom of the UI, next to the color pallet, there is a `Caption` section where you can choose a property to be shown as the caption for all the nodes of the selected label.